# Allocate two ListViews inside an ScrollView (or something like that) apparently impossible

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have been "fighting" for two days trying to find a solution to this design but apparently it is impossible.

Scenario: 
The View (activity) with 4 LinearLayouts and below must have a container (I have been trying with ScrollView + LinearLayouts) with 2 ListViews (with a TextView title for each one), and yet, these ListViews will vary according to some choices made in another ListView coming from a Dialog.
Firstly, when nothing is added yet the View is exactly as should be, but when I add, let's say 3 items, then the disaster shows up.
The first ListView becomes huge (in height size) and the other one goes down there, out of view.

I have tried lots of combinations of layouts but no success so far, tried even resize the ListView via java code after adding items to its adapter.

```
Util.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(listViewCaixasSelecionadas);
```

The initial view - this is OK:
[image]

Dialog to choose some items to add to ListView adapter:
[image]

Three items add to the ListView (see the huge space below the last item):
[image]

View of the second ListView, which now I must scroll a lot to see it:
 [image]

Print from eclipse project:
[image]

Here is my layout xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutTerceiraTela"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/include_user_emp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBotoes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/include2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSalvarParte3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Salvar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdicionarCaixa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+Caixa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdicionarProduto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+Produto" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTituloTela"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutBotoes"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNomeProcedimento"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Nome do Procedimento"
        android:textColor="@color/branco"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBarTela3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTituloTela"
    layout="@layout/include_progress_overlay" />

<!-- Scroll com as duas listas -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/containerCaixasProdutos"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewBottomWindow"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutTituloTela"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutScrollCaixasProdutos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTituloDialog"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Caixas"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/branco"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewCaixas"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Produtos (Opcionais)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/branco"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewProdutosAdicionados"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#4A9C67" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewBottomWindow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_cab_done_focused_csa" />
```

I really would appreciate any idea how to solve this issue, absolutely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to measure height

```
public void setDynamicListViewHeight(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
                return;
        }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 0;
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Measuring and setting height it's not working, that's what I said above, I have this method to set dynamic height, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

May be adding weights to the views may solve your problem. Let me know ur problem solved or not.

Comment: Not solved yet, but I gave up it for the moment, spending a lot of time trying, it's not worth it, trying another approach.

Comment: ok. sorry. I guessed it. Today I will try to solve it if I have time.